# You can buy these from the supermarket. / ...supermarkets

Tags: articles, uncountable-nouns, transatlantic-differences

Question: Where can I buy these cakes?

Answer 1-You can buy these from **the supermarket.** (to refer to any supermarkets)

Answer 2-You can buy these from **supermarkets.**

I think that we can say **".......the supermarket"** to refer to a particular supermarket and to refer to any supermarket, but I am not quite sure if I might also say or if I have to say **"........from supermarkets.** (without article **the** before supermarkets" to refer to any supermarket.

Are both usages correct?

Comment: I'm not convinced many native Anglophones would use singular ***the supermarket*** to refer to "supermarkets in general" the way Brits might say ***Let's go down the pub*** without necessarily even having any particular pub in mind. Just as you'd rarely hear the singular in, say, *I'm offering you this bottle of perfume at the bargain price of only £5! It would cost you at least £40 in the **shop / shops**!*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not entirely convinced. I feel sure we might well say to a friend, without having any awareness of which supermarket they used, when recommending a product "Next time you are in the supermarket take a look". The definite article would imply their regular routinely visited supermarket. But if we were referring to any one of a number, one would obviously use the indefinite. -"Next time you are in a supermartket take a look".

Comment: @FumbleFingers This Canadian anglophone certainly would use "the supermarket" in the same way we'd say "go down to the pub" or "catch the bus" or "listen to the radio".

Comment: @gotube Same in the U.S., "the supermarket" can definitely refer to supermarkets generally. I actually find "You can buy these from supermarkets" stranger to the ear.

Comment: Yes, if I used the plural I would definitely leave out the article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first answer could mean "That supermarket that we both know".  It is also possible that the speaker doesn't really have a specfic supermarket in mind. But even then, its not really about supermarkets in general, but about the supermarkets that I have knowledge of. However the situation is flexible enough that it doesn't really matter.

It is certainly possible to say "You can buy them at supermarkets", that seems to be a little more general, and even "at a supermarket" is possible.